# Is there another way to pause the music in my LOVE2D game?

Tags: lua, love2d

I am working with a **LOVE2D** game and I am implementing a pause feature. I actually have this function in my Lua file. It includes a scrolling movement and I want to press P to stop the game for a bit.

My code is shown here:

```
if love.keyboard.wasPressed('p') and scrolling == true then
    scrolling = false
    sounds['music']:pause()
    sounds['pause']:play()
end
```

My problem is on line 3, because I added a field called pause. It doesn't make sense since I looked at the wiki that it is there in vversions 11.0 above.

Is there any other function I can call?

Comment: I have no idea what love2d is but maybe https://love2d.org/wiki/love.audio.stop?

Comment: how is anyone supposed to know what `sounds['music']` is?  and what is wrong with version 11.0? and why does that not make sense? your talking in riddles.

Comment: **Update*** Nevermind, I found a different problem and solved it already.